# Question about awarding a bonus

Tags: discussion

I self-answered [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/99819/what-portion-of-the-fee-to-my-mds-concierge-medical-practice-is-eligible-for-us) about the IRS, but I am not 100% satisfied with my own answer, as a little crevice of ambiguity remains.  I'd really like an answer with no ambiguity quoting an extremely reliable source, and am willing to offer a bonus for such an answer.

However, I don't have rep to speculate with. My question is, if no one posts a better answer than mine, can I award the bonus to myself?  I will judge the answers fairly.  I hesitated to provide a link to the question, because I am not fishing for votes, I just want the question answered better than I could do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you [can't award the bounty to yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97802/132930) - apparently this was earlier possible, but even then [you didn't get the reputation for it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/132930).

Comment: Thanks.  The Q is an IRS question, so I will go with my answer, and in 7 years or less, I'll get an answer from the IRS. :)